# Dropdown doesn't show menu items until I mouseover

Tags: jquery

I am trying to learn jquery and I got an example of a dropdown menu like following:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>CSS Dropdown</title>

<style type="text/css">

    /* General */
    #cssdropdown, #cssdropdown ul { list-style: none; }
    #cssdropdown, #cssdropdown * { padding: 0; margin: 0; }

    /* Head links */
    #cssdropdown li.headlink { width: 220px; float: left; margin-left: -1px; border: 1px black solid; background-color: #e9e9e9; text-align: center; }
    #cssdropdown li.headlink a { display: block; padding: 15px; }

    /* Child lists and links */
    #cssdropdown li.headlink ul { display: none; border-top: 1px black solid; text-align: left; }
    #cssdropdown li.headlink:hover ul { display: block; }
    #cssdropdown li.headlink ul li a { padding: 5px; height: 17px; }
    #cssdropdown li.headlink ul li a:hover { background-color: #333; }

    /* Pretty styling */
    body { font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 0.8em; background-color: black; }
    #cssdropdown a { color: white; } #cssdropdown ul li a:hover { text-decoration: none; }
    #cssdropdown li.headlink { background-color: white; background-image: url(bg.gif); }
    #cssdropdown li.headlink ul { background-image: url(bg.gif); background-position: bottom; padding-bottom: 10px; }
</style>
<script language="JavaScript">
    window.onload = function()
    {
        var lis = document.getElementById('cssdropdown').getElementsByTagName('li');
        for(i = 0; i < lis.length; i++)
        {
            var li = lis[i];
            if (li.className == 'headlink')
            {
                li.onmouseover = function() { this.getElementsByTagName('ul').item(0).style.display = 'block'; }
                li.onmouseout = function() { this.getElementsByTagName('ul').item(0).style.display = 'none'; }
            }
        }
    }
    /* or with jQuery:
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#cssdropdown li.headlink').hover(
            function() { $('ul', this).css('display', 'block'); },
            function() { $('ul', this).css('display', 'none'); });
    });
    */
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <ul id="cssdropdown">

        <li class="headlink">
            <a href="http://google.com/">Search Engines</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://google.com/">Google</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://yahoo.com/">Yahoo</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://live.com/">Live Search</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="headlink">
            <a href="http://shopping.com">Shopping</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://amazon.com/">Amazon</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://ebay.com/">eBay</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://craigslist.com/">CraigsList</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

However, it works strangely for me means dropdown menu works but I can only found menu items if I slide onto it.

Comment: I'm confused what is the question?

Comment: @Simon, can you kindly run the code, you will understand it. I want to know where is the error ?

Comment: @AnkitGautam, how to change it in jquery thus it works ?

Comment: @J.Steen, how to change it in jquery thus it works ? Look I am very new in web languages. So have very few knowledge in it.

Comment: @alessandro no there is juery wrapped in comment so i didn't see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem, it is that when you hover one of the dropdown menus then the box that appears is just white, and you have to move the cursor over the links so that they change color and can be seen. To fix this you need to change the styling. Either change

```
#cssdropdown li.headlink ul
```

to have a different background (it has inherited the white background from the parent element) and/or change the styling of

```
#cssdropdown li.headlink ul li a
```

Try changing the background property of these elements and see what happens.

Edit: Or change the `color` attribute on `#cssdropdown li.headlink ul li a` because the text in these elements are white, and thus invisible against the white background.

Comment: Page background is set to black by this line: `body { font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 0.8em; background-color: black; }` This means that the `body` element (which contains all the things that you see) has a black background (`background-color: black;`)